# How do I set the Coordinate Reference System for a NetCDF file through a configuration file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I have downloaded some NetCDF files (.nc) from the following link: http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/~atmos/martin/?page_id=140. However, when I open these files in QGIS, they do not align with my vector layer.

To realign them, I currently convert the NetCDF filed to GeoTIFF files and then specify the following CRS through a TFW file:

0.0100000000 
 0.0000000000 
 0.0000000000 
-0.0100000000 
-179.9950000000 
 69.9950000000

Is there a way for me to set the CRS for NetCDF files directly through  configuration files, without converting them to GeoTIFF?

Comment: What CRS is represented in your example TFW file?

Comment: Dear nmtoken: Thank you for your response. The details of the TFW file are shared in the post - it contains 6 rows with the entries 0.010 0.000 0.000 -0.010 -179.995 69.995. Essentially, the GIS information has a resolution of 0.01 x 0.01° and spans from 70° N - 55° S and 180° W - 180° E.

Comment: I saw those details but the question was about the CRS represented, there's nothing in those details to say which CRS is represented, is the assumption that it's EPSG:4326 for example?

Comment: Oh, sorry - perhaps I used the incorrect terminology in my question. No information on the CRS is present in the TFW file. However, when I open the file in QGIS, I select the EPSG: 4326, WGS 84 coordinate system. Thank you, once again!